# If x^x^x=y^y, express y in terms of x

Tags: algebra

This question is one of my friend think out suddenly and asked me how to do, but I have no idea how to do it, anyone have ideas? (even my friend don't know how to do it, he just think up the question)

Im not sure if it is possible to be done or not

Comment: That's the definition of low quality! Please, clarify if you want to use Mathematica to solve this or if this is a Maths question. Please, show the minimal effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because (apart from reading like a homework question and showing no effort at a solution) it is not clear, if this is a Mathematica related question.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem tends to have a lot of branch cut difficulties. If you're interested in $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, then I'd recommend starting with a [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) to make sure we're on the right track:

```
ContourPlot[x^x^x == y^y, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image]

It looks like $x>0$ for all solutions. Let's solve under this assumption:

```
Assuming[x > 0, Solve[x^x^x == y^y, y] // FullSimplify]
```

> *Solve*: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

```
(*    {{y -> E^ProductLog[x^x Log[x]]}}    *)
```

Almost there. Now we need to know that the `ProductLog` has two real-valued branches:

```
Table[E^ProductLog[k, x^x Log[x]], {k, -1, 0}]
(*    {E^ProductLog[-1, x^x Log[x]], E^ProductLog[x^x Log[x]]}    *)
```

Plot these:

```
Plot[{E^ProductLog[-1, x^x Log[x]], E^ProductLog[x^x Log[x]]},
     {x, 0, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Looks like the contour plot!

Answer (score 1):

```
Reduce[x^x^x == y^y, y, Reals]
```

> `((y/2 | C[1]) \[Element] Integers && C[1] <= -2 &&  x^x^x == (-C[1])^C[1] && y == C[1]) || (x^x^x == -1 &&  y == -1) || (((1 + y)/2 | C[1]) \[Element] Integers && C[1] <= -2 && x^x^x == -(-C[1])^C[1] && y == C[1]) || (x^x^x == 1 &&  y == 1) || (E^(-1/E) <= x^x^x <  1 && (y == E^ProductLog[Log[x^x^x]] ||  y == E^ProductLog[-1, Log[x^x^x]])) || (x^x^x > 1 &&  y == E^ProductLog[Log[x^x^x]])`

```
Reduce[x^x^x == y^y, y, PositiveReals]
```

> `(x^x^x == 1 &&  y == 1) || (E^(-1/E) <= x^x^x <  1 && (y == E^ProductLog[Log[x^x^x]] ||  y == E^ProductLog[-1, Log[x^x^x]])) || (x^x^x > 1 &&  y == E^ProductLog[Log[x^x^x]])`

```
Reduce[x^x^x == y^y, y, Complexes]
```

> `(C[1] \[Element] Integers && x^x^x != 0 && y != 0 &&  2 I \[Pi] C[1] + Log[x^x^x] !=  0 && ((Im[ProductLog[-1, 2 I \[Pi] C[1] + Log[x^x^x]]] > -\[Pi] && y == E^ProductLog[-1, 2 I \[Pi] C[1] + Log[x^x^x]]) ||  y == E^ProductLog[ 2 I \[Pi] C[1] +  Log[x^x^x]] || (Im[ ProductLog[1, 2 I \[Pi] C[1] + Log[x^x^x]]] <= \[Pi] &&  y == E^ProductLog[1, 2 I \[Pi] C[1] + Log[x^x^x]]))) || (x^x^ x == 1 && y == 1)`